# Newton's Method for initial approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

In order to find an approximation to the root of the equation $-x^3-\cos x=0$ by using Newton's method, which of the following initial approximations can be chosen?
$x_0=1 , x_0=0, x_0=2 , x_0=1$ or $x_0=0$ and $x_0=1$ Which one?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Many students are doing online assessments at the moment, so you are very unlikely to get an answer to such a question. At least I hope it is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the function, you will see that the only solution is $x\approx-0.865474$. Try all of these initial values in your code and you will see, what happens. In one case it converges however only if the damped Newton is used.